# Is there a way to let JVM load customized java.io.File instead of the standard one

Tags: java, class, system, customization

Added some field in java.io.File and compiled it to jar locally.
Now I want to import it in application which uses that field.
But `javac -classpath myio.jar Test.java` won't compile.
Using reflection and invoke `java -classpath myio.jar Test`  got runtime error about
no such field.
The File has to be packaged as java.io. Is there a way to force JVM load the local
java.io.File or it's forbidden?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What does java.io.File not give you?

Comment: why didn't you just subclass `File`?

Comment: let me get this right - you create a class which inherits from `java.io.File` or simply implemented `java.io.File` in your jar? How could this possibly work? Why not call it `com.my.ExtendedFile` or something else - and then use that in your code?

Comment: An extraordinary question requires extraordinary justification before people will take it seriously.  What is your extraordinary justification?  Please, amaze me.

Comment: OK, it's because of android. They have a different java core library implementation. I want to port some of the files.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to force JVM load the local java.io.File or it's forbidden?

It is forbidden.

You could *possibly* work around this by compiling your "customize" `File` class and adding it to the bootclasspath ... but it is a **really bad idea** to do this for anything other than an experiment.

---

> It's because of android. They have a different java core library implementation. I want to port some of the files.

If you want to port code from Android to Java (TM), you should be changing your code to remove the platform dependencies, NOT changing the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The File Class in jdk is loaded firstly, so your class will not be loaded.
You can place you class into jdk(rt.jar), if there's no compile error, it should work.